# How to not have PowerBI bookmark impact other bookmarks?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

I have four bookmarks for my report: Open nav bar (to show slicers), Close the nav bar (to hide slicers), Show graph for data filtered, show table view for data filtered.

Current state in the report - is when the user opens the nav bar bookmark it defaults to the "show visual" bookmark. How do I set up the report so no matter what bookmark is selected by the user (graph or tabular), it stays on that current bookmark when they open up the nav bar?

Basically, just want the bookmarks to be fluid with each other.

[Power BI Report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gHPU.png)

Answer (score 0):

In the View -> Bookmarks tab, hover over a bookmark to see an ellipses. Click the ellipses and you'll notice "All visuals" and "Selected visuals" at the bottom. The Selected visuals option allows you to point bookmarks at specific objects.